# linux script to run commands within a command

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, ksh, redhat

First of all I am very weak in scripting, so please bear with this algorithm only for explanation of my issue:

Phase 1: Get all information from Server-1, and save it in a text file.
Phase 2: Copy the text file to Server-2 and rerun the script to create similar information that was present in Server-1

Phase 1:

file1.txt:

> row1
>
> row2
>
> row3
>
> row4

If I run command1 on row1 of file1.txt, it would give me a output as below:

```
./command1 row1 > output
```

cat output

> > Winter: 1456
> >
> > Summer: 5467
> >
> > Spring: 2314
> >
> > Fall: 3443

Similarly all other rows with command1 will have 4 other outputs with different season's code.
4 outputs is for simiplicity. The one I have - deals with has around 40 output in each commands output.

Now I need to know how to put these 16 outputs in a output.txt so that i can re-create the same information in another server?

--

Update After @mofoe 's reply:

Hey, first of all thank you. I think this is going in the right direction.
So i think this brings me upto the last step of orginising the output so that it would be useful in inputing this data back in another server.

Consider this ping command with a static output, and disregard any dynamic or changing values, think of it, its some commands output that would be used to enter in another server located elsewhere. Since many different commands would be run to enter into the system, not something like it can be done with pasting the whole text file or whole lines only. only some part is important and needed. Again, i really appreciate for even replying to a lame question. thank you.

So this is where we stand now. I am using Ping command to explain you the situation, it really doesn't have anything to do with pings. Consider it a standard and static output form some other command.

```
[root@host-11 test]# cat file1.txt
#only 2 hosts are typed in here, originally there are 500+
host-11
host-12

[root@host-11 test]# cat script
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
    /bin/ping -c 4 $line >> output.txt
done < file1.txt

[root@host-11 test]# cat output.txt
PING host-11 (x.x.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host-11 (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
64 bytes from host-11 (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
64 bytes from host-11 (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from host-11 (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms

--- host-11 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.023/0.032/0.038/0.009 ms
PING host-12 (y.y.y.y) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host-12 (y.y.y.y): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.228 ms
64 bytes from host-12 (y.y.y.y): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.267 ms
64 bytes from host-12 (y.y.y.y): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.264 ms
64 bytes from host-12 (y.y.y.y): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.246 ms

--- host-12 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.228/0.251/0.267/0.019 ms
```

So now, I need the text file in an organised way, something like this:

cat output.txt

```
host-name      IP       icmp_seq1     icmp_seq2    rtt  

host-11:    (x.x.x.x)   time=0.023  time=0.036  0.023/0.032/0.038/0.009

host-12:    (y.y.y.y)   time=0.228  time=0.267  0.228/0.251/0.267/0.019



** all other hosts that might have been included in the file1.txt
```

So once I have this, i would have to run 4 different commands to input this in the other server. I hope it makes more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do 
    ./command1 $line >> output.txt
done < file1.txt
```

This script iterates over every line in `file1.txt`, runs `./command1` with the line and appends the output to `output.txt`

Comment: my reply to you was long therefore added it in the description of my issue. please check, and let me know. Thanks..